# Why no StringBuilder.+=(String) in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

This behavior seems to be broken (I am using Scala 2.9.1)

```
var b= new StringBuilder
```

These are OK:

```
b+='a'
b.append('b') 
b.append("de")
```

This produces compile error:

```
b+="de"
```

Any idea as to why only StringBuilder#+=(c: Char) exists whereas both StringBuilder#append(c:Char) and StringBuilder#append(s:String) happily co-exist? What is wrong with declaring and implementing StringBuilder#+=(s: String)?

Is it oversight or some deeper problem in the Scala type system?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try `b ++= "de"`. A `String` is considered a collection of `Char`s.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. ++= is bearable, I still would hope that Scala type system is intelligent enough to tell String from Char ;-)

Comment: It is, that's why you have to use a different method.

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer. My point is that I don't want to use a different method (or remember that I have to use different method in this situation). This is why I think it is broken.

Comment: As far as I can tell, in 2.9, `++=` is defined in a generic way in `Growable` as `def ++=(xs: TraversableOnce[A]): this.type = { xs.seq foreach += ; this }`, which might not be very efficient. But Scala 2.10's `StringBuilder` overrides `++=` for efficiency.

Comment: I don't disagree that `+=` could be made to also accept `String`s to make things simpler, but that breaks consistency with the other collection classes & methods.

Comment: Actually is the contrary, this maintains the consistency: in all mutable collections, `++=` is used to append other collections, while `+=` only a single element. Also in this case then, `+=` is used to append a char (a single element) and `++=` a string (a collection)

Comment: @Novalink Yes, this is what I wrote. We agree.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet I'm afraid I didn't read well your message, sorry, you're right.